# UFW Couldn't determine iptables version

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, yocto, ufw

I am building a custom embedded Linux platform based on the NXP i.MX8 with Yocto. I want to use UFW to setup the firewall. When I boot the system and try to use UFW it returns an error

```
Couldn't determine iptables version.
```

I have the iptables and nftables packages installed. I have tried to manually change the itpables symlink to point to the iptables-legacy binary. It still fails. How can I fix this? Please see the versions below.

```
    root@iot-gate-imx8plus:~# iptables -v
    iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): no command specified
    Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
    root@iot-gate-imx8plus:~# nft -v
    nftables v1.0.2 (Lester Gooch)
    root@iot-gate-imx8plus:~# ufw version
    ufw 0.36.2
    Copyright 2008-2023 Canonical Ltd.
    root@iot-gate-imx8plus:~# ufw status
    ERROR: Couldn't determine iptables version
    root@iot-gate-imx8plus:~# uname -r
    5.15.32+g07c574e56d60
    root@iot-gate-imx8plus:~#
```

iptables:

```
    root@iot-gate-imx8plus:/usr/sbin# ls -lrt *iptables*

>    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar  9  2018 iptables-save -> xtables-legacy-multi\
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar  9  2018 iptables-restore -> xtables-legacy-multi\
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar  9  2018 iptables-legacy-save -> xtables-legacy-multi\
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar  9  2018 iptables-legacy-restore -> xtables-legacy-multi\
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar  9  2018 iptables-legacy -> xtables-legacy-multi\
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar  9  2018 iptables -> xtables-legacy-multi
```

**UPDATE**:

Strace pointed out the problem. UFW makes an assumption of where the iptables binary is and Yocto installed it somewhere else:

```
strace: Process 700 attached
[pid   700] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/fd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid   700] execve("/sbin/iptables", ["/sbin/iptables", "-V"], 0xffffec437b88 /* 21 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid   700] +++ exited with 255 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=700, si_uid=0, si_status=255, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
ERROR: Couldn't determine iptables version
+++ exited with 1 +++
root@iot-gate-imx8plus:~# which iptables
/usr/sbin/iptables
root@iot-gate-imx8plus:~# ln -sf /usr/sbin/iptables /sbin/iptables
root@iot-gate-imx8plus:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Comment: Can you share on a pastebin the output of `strace -f -s 1000 -e trace=file ufw status` ?

Comment: You helped me figure it out - thank you. If you want to write an answer I will accept it and allocate the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `strace -f -s 1000 -e trace=file ufw status` to figure out which files path are used, you could discover something wrong.